# Selective hopper minecart unloading

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I have a 1.14 automatic wheat farm that involves a hopper minecart picking up wheat under a field of villagers. However, I only want to collect the wheat and leave the seeds so that the villagers can collect and replant them. In order to do this, I have one wheat in each slot in the minecart. This system works perfectly and only picks up wheat.

However, now I want to create an automatic unloader. The unloader cannot unload all the items though, as I need all 5 slots filled with some wheat. My plan was to use a detector rail with a comparator and a redstone hopper. This would unload all items down to 22, and then send the minecart on its way. The comparator detection works, but the problem is the detector rail is sending a redstone high to the hopper underneath it, preventing any unloading.

Any suggestions for getting the hopper to unload despite the detector rail above it? Or any alternate design suggestions? Image of a partially working system attached:

[image]

Comment: I think the best options are either bouncing it back and forth between hopper and detector rail until the signal decreases enough or first detecting how many items there are and then timing how long to put it onto the hopper or emptying it completely and then re-filling it (but then you could at most pick up 63 items at a time).

Comment: I believe John's answer is one good solution, though it could use some fleshing out.

However, your original question implies a misunderstanding of the mechanics of villager farms. As the villager harvests the crops, he will pick up the seeds. Any left over will fall to the ground. Later on, your minecart will come along and pick them up.

If you are having trouble with your villager ceasing to plant, it's possible he has filled his inventory with wheat and has no seeds to plant. The best way to avoid this is to fill his inventory with 8 stacks of seeds before you put him in the farm.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding, is you want a way to unload a hopper minecart, and leave it with some wheat in it, so that it will only pick up wheat on it's next trip.

This is a sketch of a solution.

- Put four pieces of cobble into the hopper minecart.
- Have your unloading station contain an item sorter accepting only wheat.
- Once the minecart is completely unloaded of wheat, as it departs, you can force a single wheat into the empty slot, to ensure only wheat gets loaded on the outbound trip.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else interested, I found a hacky solution. You can use a regular rail and a detector rail on a slope and force the minecart between the rails using a piston. The detector rail will activate and the hopper will unload.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your solution?